# External Drive Data is not available on other OS other than Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, backup, ntfs, external-hdd

I have 1 TB HDD . It was working well both in Ubuntu and windows , But three days go I can see my data and folders in Ubuntu only . But when I insert this HDD on other system having windows it is detected but not showing any folder . But when I check properties it shows me exactly how much disk space is available .
I don't have space to backup my data and format drive my HDD is almost full

Here are my HDD details :

```
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x27ddc48f

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   134146047    67072000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       134146048   297983999    81918976    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       297986046   625121279   163567617    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       461836683   625121279    81642298+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       452085291   461836619     4875664+  82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7       297986048   452083704    77048828+  83  Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000170586112 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121597 cylinders, total 1953458176 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00023f15

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048  1953458175   976728064    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Any Help will 
Note: I don't have other Drive to backup my data , my drive is getting recognized on other system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tired these steps on windows and it works for me

Click on "Start" --> In search bar, type cmd. Right-click on the command prompt

that appears in the search and select "Run as administrator".

"Command Prompt" will be opened.

(If you are using Windows XP then open the command prompt directly)

Here I assume your external hard disk drive letter as G:

Enter this command.

```
attrib -h -r -s /s /d g:\*.*
```

You can copy the above command --> Right-click in the Command Prompt and

paste it.

Note : Replace the letter g with your external hard disk drive letter.

Now check for your files in external hard disk.